# How can I add a part of log message inside the Datadog notification?

Tags: notifications, datadog

I have been trying to include log message body inside the notification, but couldn't.
The actual log contains all the attributes in the 'Event Attributes' properly, but I couldn't find a way to include the value of the attributes in the notification body.

For example, the target log contains an event attribute 'thread_name' with a value of '123'.
But when I tried to use that value in the notification body with {{thread_name}} or {{thread_name.name}}, it never shows in the actual notification email.

In the reference docs, I couldn't find how to get the message attribute values, except for the predefined variables.

Is it even possible to include log message values in the notification?

Answer (score 0):

The log message can now be referenced by using {{log.message}}. You can also reference additional variables like {{log.attributes}} and {{log.tags}}.

More details are here: https://docs.datadoghq.com/monitors/notify/variables/?tab=is_alert#matching-attributetag-variables

Comment: Does it not work in test notifications? I tried to use it through tests but the attributes were not getting populated